# Shell equivalent of php preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, shell, grep

Is there a shell equivalent of PHP's preg_match?

I'm trying to extract the database name from this string in a shell script.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'somedb');
```

Using preg_match in PHP I could just do something like this.

```
preg_match('define(\'DB_NAME\','(.*)'\'\)',$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ t="define('DB_NAME', 'somedb');"
$ echo $t
define('DB_NAME', 'somedb');
$ eval "result=(${t##*,}"
$ echo $result
somedb
$
```

That one does contain a bashism, and while it will work in most out-of-the-box environments, to stick with posix shell features, do the clunkier version:

```
t="define('DB_NAME', 'somedb');"
r="${t##*,}"
r="${r%);*}"
r=`eval echo $r`
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Stackoverflow is amazing.

Any chance you would be willing to explain how eval "result=(${t##*,}" works?

Comment: you are playing with the fact the substition come back with '); at the end this is nice but kind of not scalabale a lot (ie: easy to modify) but nice....

Comment: ${t##*,} deletes the prefix string up through ",", see sh(1) or bash(1). This leaves 'somedb'); to deal with, so I added result=( in front with an eval, which got rid of the quotes and took advantage of the fact that bash lets you do assignments with =(...). CB is kinda right, but he missed the worst part of this expression: I think it's a bashism, and wouldn't work in a posix shell.

Comment: Definitely want to give CB credit for figuring it out, though :-)

Comment: In your posix version, you can eliminate using `eval` if you replace the two lines before it with `r="${t##*@(,|, )\'}"` and `r="${r%\')*}"` - note that this also handles the case where there's no space after the comma.

Answer (score 3):

Use of expr answers exactly to the question :

```
expr match "string" "regexp"
```

So, for your need, you may write :

```
expr match "$mystring" "define('DB_NAME', '\([^']\+\)');"
```

Note the `\( \)` pair.
Without these characters, expr will return the number of matched chars.
With them, only the matching part is returned.

```
$ string="define('DB_NAME', 'toto');"
$ expr match "$string" "define('DB_NAME', '[^']\+');"
26

$ string="define('DB_NAME', 'toto');"
$ expr match "$string" "define('DB_NAME', '\([^']\+\)');"
toto
```

I don't know under which environments expr is available (and has this behaviour), though.

Comment: This answers the title of the question best, although the accepted answer provides a complete solution to the body of the question, despite not answering the title question.  It's worth noting that `expr` outputs the number of matched characters and exits with a code appropriate to its result, which can be used directly in a test. However, in this case, the output should be redirected to /dev/null if you don't want the script to spit out the number of matches all the time.

Comment: This behaviour may depends on the version used; but under the bash of ubuntu, expr match output depends on whether there are \( \) pairs in the pattern. If there aren't, then you're right, it outputs the number of chars matched. If there are, only the part matched between the \( \) is returned.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$ str="define('DB_NAME', 'somedb');"
$ php -r "$str echo DB_NAME;"
somedb
```

Comment: Thanks for the creative solution

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you want

```
sed -e "/DB_NAME/ s/define('DB_NAME', '\(.*\)');/\1/" /path/to/file/to/search.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
MATCHED=$(sed -n "s/^define('DB_NAME', '\(.*\)')/\1/p" file.php)

if [[ -n ${MATCHED} ]];then
  echo $MATCHED
else
  echo "No match found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the case/esac construct

```
mystring="define('DB_NAME', 'somedb');"
case $mystring in
    *define*DB_NAME*) 
      dbname=${mystring%\'*}
      dbname=${dname##*\'}
      echo "$dbname" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This code doesn't do quite what I'm trying to.  I'm trying to extract the value from the string.

Comment: then just do your string manipulation to get dbname inside the case/esac structure....nothing too difficult...